# Stacked bar chart in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

How can I make a stacked bar chart in Google Earth Engine?

Earth Engine's docs for `ui.chart()` refers to [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts) for customization options. That API suggests to set `isStacked = true` in the charts options. I tried, but it still plots the bars individually (doesn't stack them). What am I missing?

[Link to code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/07a399cbf92e9aecbaf10f2bbed20729). Code also pasted below for reference.

```
var dataTable = {
  cols: [{id: 'name', label: 'Classes', type: 'string'},
         {id: 'percentage', label: '(%)', type: 'number'}],

  rows: [{c: [{v: 'A'}, {v: 60}]},
        {c: [{v: 'B'}, {v: 40}]}]
  };
// Define a dictionary of customization options.
var options = {
  legend: {position: 'none'},
  padding:0,
  hAxis: {
    minValue:0,
    maxValue:100
  },
  height:'80px',
  isStacked: true //<=following google's recommendations. 
};
// Make a BarChart from the table and the options.
var chart = new ui.Chart(dataTable, 'BarChart', options);
print(chart)
```

Comment: I think it's because GEE is confused about your `dataTable`. It's expecting a 2-D array as input, while you give it a dictionary. Have tested a 2-D array `[['Type', 'A', 'B'], ['Value', 40, 60]]` and this works just fine.

Comment: You were right. Changing it to `var dataTable = [['Type', 'A', 'B'], ['Value', 40, 60]]` worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create stacked bar charts with Earth Engine charting functions. I see your example is using a datatable, though the more common method would be to create one from a feature collection. Here is an example for a feature collection where each feature is an ecoregion zone and properties for each feature are 12 months of precipitation.

```js
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

// Define some ecoregion features.
var desert = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-109.21, 31.42, -108.3, 32.03),
        {label: 'Desert', value: 0});

var forest = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-122.73, 43.45, -122.28, 43.91),
        {label: 'Forest', value: 1});

var grassland = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-101.81, 41.7, -100.53, 42.51),
        {label: 'Grassland', value: 2});

// Combine features into a feature collection.
var ecoregions = ee.FeatureCollection([desert, forest, grassland]);

// Load PRISM climate normals image collection; convert images to bands.
var normClim = ee.ImageCollection('OREGONSTATE/PRISM/Norm81m')
  .toBands();

// Add mean climate properties to each ecorgeion.
ecoregions = normClim.reduceRegions({
  collection: ecoregions,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 5e4});

// Make an absolute stacked bar chart.
print(
  ui.Chart.image.byRegion({
  image: normClim.select('[0-9][0-9]_ppt|label'),
  regions: ecoregions,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 500,
  xProperty: 'label'})
  .setSeriesNames(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                     'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'])
  .setChartType('ColumnChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Average Monthly Precipitation by Ecoregion',
    hAxis: {title: 'Ecoregion'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Precipitation (mm)'},
    colors: ['604791', '1d6b99', '39a8a7', '0f8755', '76b349', 'f0af07',
            'e37d05', 'cf513e', '96356f', '724173', '9c4f97', '696969'],
    isStacked: 'absolute',
  })
);

// Make relative stacked bar chart.
print(
  ui.Chart.image.byRegion({
  image: normClim.select('[0-9][0-9]_ppt|label'),
  regions: ecoregions,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 500,
  xProperty: 'label'})
  .setSeriesNames(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                     'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'])
  .setChartType('ColumnChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Average Monthly Precipitation by Ecoregion',
    hAxis: {title: 'Ecoregion'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Precipitation (mm)'},
    colors: ['604791', '1d6b99', '39a8a7', '0f8755', '76b349', 'f0af07',
            'e37d05', 'cf513e', '96356f', '724173', '9c4f97', '696969'],
    isStacked: 'relative',
  })
);
```

[Code Editor link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/aa34023c07647c223a9c2a2ca8962912)

[image]