# How can the order of labels in a Google Earth Engine chart be edited?

Tags: google-earth-engine

This is a follow-up question to the post  ["Stacked bar chart in Google Earth Engine"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363345/stacked-bar-chart-in-google-earth-engine) concerning the [there-referenced code in the answer](https://code.earthengine.google.com/aa34023c07647c223a9c2a2ca8962912).

Looking at the labels of the plot in the console, the order is as expected (Jan to Dec). As soon as I open the plot in full size though, the order of the labels is reversed (Dec to Jan). This only happens if the option `isStacked` is NOT set to `false`.

Why does this happen and how can it be avoided? I would like the months to be in ordered Jan to Dec with a stacked graph. The code of the above-referenced answer is pasted below for reference.

```
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

// Define some ecoregion features.
var desert = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-109.21, 31.42, -108.3, 32.03),
        {label: 'Desert', value: 0});

var forest = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-122.73, 43.45, -122.28, 43.91),
        {label: 'Forest', value: 1});
    
var grassland = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-101.81, 41.7, -100.53, 42.51),
        {label: 'Grassland', value: 2});

// Combine features into a feature collection.
var ecoregions = ee.FeatureCollection([desert, forest, grassland]);

// Load PRISM climate normals image collection; convert images to bands.
var normClim = ee.ImageCollection('OREGONSTATE/PRISM/Norm81m')
  .toBands();
  
// Add mean climate properties to each ecorgeion.
ecoregions = normClim.reduceRegions({
  collection: ecoregions,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 5e4});

// Make an absolute stacked bar chart.
print(
  ui.Chart.image.byRegion({
  image: normClim.select('[0-9][0-9]_ppt|label'),
  regions: ecoregions,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 500,
  xProperty: 'label'})
  .setSeriesNames(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                     'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'])
  .setChartType('ColumnChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Average Monthly Precipitation by Ecoregion',
    hAxis: {title: 'Ecoregion'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Precipitation (mm)'},
    colors: ['604791', '1d6b99', '39a8a7', '0f8755', '76b349', 'f0af07',
            'e37d05', 'cf513e', '96356f', '724173', '9c4f97', '696969'],
    isStacked: 'absolute',
  })
);

// Make relative stacked bar chart.
print(
  ui.Chart.image.byRegion({
  image: normClim.select('[0-9][0-9]_ppt|label'),
  regions: ecoregions,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 500,
  xProperty: 'label'})
  .setSeriesNames(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                     'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'])
  .setChartType('ColumnChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Average Monthly Precipitation by Ecoregion',
    hAxis: {title: 'Ecoregion'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Precipitation (mm)'},
    colors: ['604791', '1d6b99', '39a8a7', '0f8755', '76b349', 'f0af07',
            'e37d05', 'cf513e', '96356f', '724173', '9c4f97', '696969'],
    isStacked: 'relative', // if this is set to false, the order of the labels is Jan to Dec
  })
);
```